# What's the difference between Application and AppDomain.CurrentDomain

Tags: c#, appdomain

I am little confused about usage of `Application` class and `AppDomain` class.
For example `Application.StartupPath` is equal to `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`

I usually used `Application` class and recently discovered `AppDomain` - Can someone explain to me `AppDomain` class and its usage?

Comment: An Application class is highly specific to a GUI app.  A console mode app or service doesn't have one.  But every .NET app has an AppDomain.  The WPF Application class is very different from the Winforms Application class.  Sure, there's a bit of duplication, not excessively so.

Comment: Can you provide more information about exactly what classes you are referring to, with namespaces? It would make the question more clear.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They have nothing in common, really.

`Application` is a class specific to Windows Forms, a .NET GUI technology. The `Application.StartupPath` is handled by the Kernel32 function `GetModuleFileName`. Through not passing a pointer to a module, the main module's path is returned - that is the `exe` file, basically.

`AppDomain` is a core .NET concept for domain isolation. Basically, it allows you to isolate (imperfectly of course) multiple applications in a single native process. Most applications only have a single `AppDomain`, but you can create as many as you like. The base path of an application domain is handled by Fusion, a .NET assembly loading technology. A very typical example would be ASP.NET applications hosted in IIS - each application has its own `AppDomain`, but they're all hosted in a single native process ("application pool"). Each logical application can be restarted without touching the others, and they don't have (simple) access to each other, but a process-tearing exception (e.g. `StackOverflowException`) will still kill the whole pool.

Another interesting class that's somewhat related is `Environment`. You can use `Environment.CommandLine` to get the process command line (which includes the path to the executable, including the name of the executable). This is basically a communication interface between the CLR and the underlying system - in this case, it takes care of saving the arguments for the application (which are passed by the OS to the `Main` function) and making them available at any time in the future.

`Environment.CommandLine` is somewhat clunky to parse (it's the raw command-line, basically - I assume it will have different conventions on Windows than on Linux, for example), but it's the only way you can *always* get to the executable. Again, `Application.StartupPath` is Winforms specific, and you can have more than one `AppDomain` - and possibly, the `AppDomain` might not even *have* a reasonable `BaseDirectory`.

The .NET Reflection APIs also give you a few ways. For example, `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()` will give you the executable assembly - however, this only works for the main `AppDomain` - other domains will have their own entry assemblies (in fact, they'll usually just return `null` :)). You can get the path to an assembly through the `Assembly.CodeBase` property, but do note that this might not always be what you expect. You can also use `Assembly.Location`, or get the `FullyQualifiedName` of any of the assembly's modules (again, most assemblies only have a single module; and again, ASP.NET is one of the prime examples of when this isn't the case).

Comment: Oh, I forgot about System.Diagnostics.Process. damn, there are so many ways

Comment: @Behrooz As far as I can tell, it uses the same logic as `Application.StartupPath` - except that it always iterates over all the modules rather than picking the main module from the get go. But yeah, it's yet another way. I wonder how many we've still missed... I mean, this wasn't meant to be an exhaustive list, but it's funny how many ways to break the egg there are, each with their own subtle differences. I hope noöne asks which is the best (at least it's off topic on SO, whew).